# Difference between EC.element_to_be_clickable and EC.presence_of_element_located to click() an element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, expected-condition

I'm getting TimeoutExceptions while clicking an element intermittently. I have tried with explicit waits and time.sleep(). It works for a while and again i get exceptions.

I want to understand if it is caused by expected condition.

```
WebDriverWait(self.driver, 40).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, <locator>  ))).click()
```

Will it help to avoid timeoutexception if I use below condition?

```
element = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, <locator>  )))
element.click()
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Are you getting the same timeout exception in both the explicit wait conditions?

Comment: `presence_of_element_located` checks if element is present is present in DOM. Not necessary that element is visible.  Refer to this - https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html

Comment: Will it be helpful to replace ```element_to_be_clickable``` with ```presence_of_element_located.``` to avoid timeoutexceptions?

Comment: Nope... it should work with `element_to_be_clickable`. If not then, the root cause is something else.

Answer (score 7):

Based on official documentation from selenium and code implementation.

[`presence_of_element_located(locator)`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) definition:

> An expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. locator - used to find the element returns the WebElement once it is located

[`element_to_be_clickable(locator)`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable):

> An Expectation for checking an element is visible and enabled such that you can click it.

Expected conditions executes the condition in a loop for a defined timeout period. It will poll until `true` is returned for the condition. If `false` is returned, it will continue the loop until maximum timeout is reached.